# How to change Selected ListItem color

Tags: android-widget

I am having one listview with background. When i click on a particular list item of that list view i want to change the color of that item.

I can be able to change the color  while focusing the list item but i want to change when the user clicks on that list item.

Any help please...

Answer (score 0):

create a  selector_file_name.xml and place on drawable folder . the content of that file (im using it with my custom drawable/images) . the idea is that you have to edit the android:states_..... with your own colors or drawables/images.

the content of that file is

```
< xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
 android:state_pressed="true" 
 android:drawable="@drawable/strishe_dhe_shigjete_bosh" />
<item 
 android:state_selected="true" 
 android:drawable="@drawable/strishe_dhe_shigjete_bosh" />
<item  
android:drawable="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

and then on the main layout file ( where you have the listview) you set the

`android:background="@drawable/selector_file_name"`